# Google chrome print preview failed

Tags: google-chrome, pdf-viewer, .net-4.8

I updated to google chrome Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I have an aspx, inside an Iframe that loads another aspx where I get the pdf file to base64 string, then send the bytes to a response with other headers, and that response goes to the browser.

Let me know of any information I can add here as I'm deciphering the code myself too and I don't know which issues are common when updating chrome.

It is fair to say that it works on IE, Edge, Firefox, Brave.

Comment: Today, all developers version chrome cannot print preview with pdfjs Edge, Firefox has not any problem. This issue is starting with version chrome 98.0.4758.102 and over one month ago. I hope anybody can help.

Comment: What issues are you having Andrew? The same as me?

Comment: Nickso, Today, many customers tell me their chrome preview failed. They are using web base PDF js generator to generate PDF file. I have seen some microsoft share point system cannot preview pdf with updated version Chrome. That problem happening over a month. Before we are using chrome developer or canary version to fixed that issue. But now, both version was not work too. I think our problem is same as you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the solution for me was that the PDF is secured via password, and it seems the new update was a security update and you cant preview a password protected pdf anymore. If I remove the password protection it works.

So in order to print it with protection you need to save it and open it via adobe acrobat and print it like that.